# Nested promises in Ionic 3 / Angular

Tags: ionic3, angular-promise

currently I have a Firebase (Angularfire2) Auth provider which would perform a user login

`signInWithEmail(credentials) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.pw);
}`

I'd call the function within my page as follows:

`login() {
    this.auth.signInWithEmail(credentials)
      .then(
        () => this.navCtrl.push(MainPage),
      (err) => {
        console.log("Return Code: " + err.code + " | Message: " + err.message);
    });
}`

However, now I'd like to nest the promise as follows:

```
signInWithEmail(credentials) {
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(() => {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.pw);
      }, (err) => {
      return Promise.reject(err); 
    });
  }
```

This does't work as void is returned, hence the signInWithEmail function can no longer be called in the current manner.

What is the best approach to actually handle the Promise of the setPersistence before the signInWithEmailAndPassword Promise is returned?

Should I just call the setPersistence method in the page itself instead of doing that in the provider?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just creating another method in my provider for the second promise:

```
enablePersistance() {
   return firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
}
```

And chaining the promises in my page:

```
this.auth.enablePersistance().then(() => {
  this.auth.signInWithEmail(credentials)
    .then(
    () => {
      console.log("Success");
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log("Return Code Login: " + err.code + " | Message: " + err.message);
    });
  }, (err) => {
  console.log("Return Code Enable Persistance: " + err.code + " | Message: " + err.message);
});
```